# upload a file via Angular form

Tags: angular, mongodb, file-upload, angular-forms

I'm working in an Angular 9 project, is a CRUD and it's already connect it to a mongo database, everything it's working fine, I'm adding tasks perfectly, but I decided to included an input for upload a image, but it's giving me a really hard time. I wil show the code of my frontend and the I will show the Backend code.

**View (HTML):**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col s5">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card content">
          <form #employeeForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addEmployee(employeeForm)">
            <input type="hidden" name="_id" #_id="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="employeeService.selectedEmployee._id">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                  <input type="text" name="name" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="employeeService.selectedEmployee.name" placeholder="Enter your name">
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <input type="text" name="position" #position="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="employeeService.selectedEmployee.position" placeholder="Enter your position">
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <input type="text" name="office" #office="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="employeeService.selectedEmployee.office" placeholder="Enter your office">
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <input type="text" name="salary" #salary="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="employeeService.selectedEmployee.salary" placeholder="Enter your salary">
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <input type="file" name="productImage" #productImage accept="image/*" [(ngModel)]="employeeService.selectedEmployee.productImage" (change)="onFileSelected($event)">
                    <button type="button" (click)="onUpload()">Upload</button>
                </div>
                <div class="card-action">
                  <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <button class="btn right" style="margin-left:0.5em;" (click)="resetForm(employeeForm)">
                      CANCEL
                    </button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn right">
                      SAVE
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**employees.component.ts:**

```
onFileSelected(event) {
  const productImage = event.target.files[0];
  return productImage;
}

addEmployee(form: NgForm, event) {
    if(form.value._id) {
      this.employeeService.putEmployee(form.value)
        .subscribe(res => {
          this.resetForm(form);
          M.toast({html: 'Edited successfuly'});
          this.getEmployees();
        });
      } else {
        this.employeeService.postEmployee(form.value)
          .subscribe(res => {
            this.resetForm(form);
            M.toast({html: 'Saved successfuly'});
            this.getEmployees();

          });
      }
  }
```

**employee.ts (models):**

```
export class Employee {
  _id: string;
  name: string;
  position: string;
  office: string;
  salary: number;
  productImage: string;

  constructor(_id = '', name = '', position = '', office = '', salary = 0, productImage = '') {
    this._id = _id;
    this.name = name;
    this.position = position;
    this.office = office;
    this.salary = salary;
    this.productImage = productImage;
  }
}
```

and for my BACKEND.

**employee.controller.js**

```
const Employee = require('../models/employee');
const employeeCtrl = {};

employeeCtrl.createEmployee = async (req, res) => {
    const employee = new Employee({
        name: req.body.name,
        position: req.body.position,
        office: req.body.office,
        salary: req.body.salary,
        productImage: req.file
    });
    await employee.save();
    res.json({
        'status': 'employee saved'
    })

};
```

**employee.routes.js :**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const multer = require('multer');
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, cb){
        cb(null, 'uploads/');
    },
    filename : function(req, file, cb){
        cb(null, file.originalname);
    }
});
const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    //reject a file
    if(file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png'){
        cb(null, true);
    } else {
        cb(new Error('The file you are trying to upload is not a image'), false);
    }
}
const upload = multer({
    storage: storage, 
    limits: {
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5
    },
    fileFilter: fileFilter
});
const subida = upload.single('productImage');
const employee = require('../controllers/employee.controller');
router.get('/', employee.getEmployees);
router.post('/', subida, employee.createEmployee);
router.get('/:id', employee.getEmployee);
router.put('/:id', employee.editEmployee);
router.delete('/:id', employee.deleteEmployee);
module.exports = router;
```

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

const { mongoose } = require('./database');

// Settings
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);


// Middlewares
app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads'));
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors({origin: 'http://localhost:4200'}));

// Routes
app.use('/api/employees', require('./routes/employee.routes'));

// Starting the server
app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log('server on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

The error I get in the server is that it cannot find the productImage path. but I don't know what to get it, to send it to server to save the employee. The employees are save perfectly without the image. it's with the image that isn't working out.

Please if someone help me or guide me because I'm new in angular.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me in a current project with smaller images (not MB in size):

```
featureImage: string;

onFileSelected(event) {
    let _t = this;
    var reader  = new FileReader();
    this.uploadedFiles = event;

    reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
        _t.featureImage = reader.result;
    }, false);

    if (event) {
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.uploadedFiles[0]);
    }
}
```

This turns the image into a base64 string stored in the variable `featureImage` then when the form is being submitted you just need to add it to the form.

```
submit(form) {
    ...
    form.productImage = this.featureImage;
    ...
}
```

Comment: hello @Steve thanks for your reply. I don'y know what's I'm doing wrong but your code it's not working for me. the reader.result give me null and the reader give me the obkect but with the result on null also.

Comment: onFileSelected(event) {
    const _t = this;
    const reader  = new FileReader();

    reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
        _t.featureImage = reader.result;
    }, false);

    if (event) {
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.uploadedFiles[0]);
    }
}

I don't really know how to apply it

Comment: Sorry, I missed a line of code which I've added to the answer now. this.uploadedFiles = event; Without that there was nothing for the reader to read and so of course it would return null. Apologies for that.